# How to obtain the functional derivative in variational inference?

Tags: variational-bayes, derivative

Referring to [David Blei's notes on variational inference](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf), I wonder how to get the derivative of $q(z_k)$, the distribution of $z_k$, in eq. 23 from eq. 22.

Namely, eq. 22 is
$L_k = \int q(z_k) \mathbb{E}_{-k}[\log p(z_k | z_{-k},x)]dz_k - \int q(z_k)\log q(z_k) dz_k$ and,

eq. 23 is
$\frac{dL_k}{dq(z_k)} = \mathbb{E}_{-k}[\log p(z_k | z_{-k},x)] - \log q(z_k) - 1$

I suppose the derivation uses functional derivatives, which I know little about. I'd very appreciate a detailed derivation.

Comment: I believe you are correct that this is a functional derivative, but the notation and the language are pure nonsense.  This becomes apparent once you realize that all appearances of "$z_k$" are as *dummy variables of integration* and therefore "$q(z_k)$" is not a part of the formula for $L_k$.  (You could just as well replace "$z_k$" by a variable "$y$", making all occurrences of "$z_k$" in the right hand side disappear, and then taking a derivative with respect to "$q(z_k)$" would become truly mysterious indeed.)

Answer (score 10):

Let's streamline the notation by fixing a function $f$ and considering a functional

$$\mathcal{L}[q] = \int (q(z) f(z) - q(z) \log(q(z))) dz.$$

A *variation* $h$ is a function for which $q+h$ is still the same kind of function as $q$ (*e.g.*, continuous or non-negative or whatever you need).  The effect of changing $q$ to $q+h$ is found in the usual way: we compare the results of $\mathcal{L}$ by subtracting the original value from the new one:

$$\eqalign{
\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta q}[h] &= \mathcal{L}[q+h] - \mathcal{L}[h] \\
&= \int \left((q+h)(z) f(z) - (q+h)(z) \log((q+h)(z)) - \left(q(z) f(z) - q(z) \log(q(z))\right)\right) dz.}$$

Let's now restrict attention to variations $h$ that have infinitesimally small values so that we may be free to neglect second-order terms.  Specifically, that means we plan to use a product-like differentiation rule to approximate the product difference

$$(q+h)(z)\log((q+h)(z)) - q(z)\log(q(z)) \approx h(z)\log(q(z)) + q(z) \frac{h(z)}{q(z)}.\tag{1}$$

To see where this came from, compare it to taking the differential of the *function* (not *functional*)

$$d(x \log(x)) = (dx) \log(x) + x \left(\frac{dx}{x}\right).$$

Plugging $(1)$ into $\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta q}[h]$, simplifying, and factoring out the common factors of $h(z)$ yields

$$\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta q}[h] = \int\left(f(z) - \log(q(z)) - 1\right) h(z) dz.$$

If this is to vanish (to second order in $h$, anyway) for *all* infinitesimal $h$, then--assuming that at each $z$ in the domain of integration there exist some variations $h$ that are nonzero in some neighborhood of $z$--the right hand side can vanish only when the coefficient of $h$ itself vanishes for all $z$; that is,

$$f(z) - \log(q(z)) - 1 = 0.$$

That's Equation 23 in the referenced notes.  It means the functional $\mathcal{L}$ is *stationary* at $q$.  That's a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for $\mathcal{L}$ to have a local extremum at $q$.

Comment: is that a typo in the equation following "by subtracting the original value from the new one:"? seems like it should be L(q+h) - L(q).

Comment: is $\delta \mathcal{L} / \delta q$ the definition of a variational derivative? Shouldn't the it at least involve a limit somewhere? My instinct/intuition suggests the fraction (LHS) was meant to come in after $h$ is taken to be infinitesimally small(?)

Comment: @user20181201 This is an "infinite dimensional" version of the derivative of a function of several real variables.  The better (more rigorous) accounts of the latter don't involve limits explicitly.  Instead, they define the derivative at a point as a linear map that approximates the function to first order as a function of Euclidean distance from that point.   See, for instance, Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds.*