# How to optimize a function with respect to a distribution, in the context of variational inference

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, optimization, references, variational-bayes

Context: I am learning about variational inference. The reference I am following is linked at the end of this post.

Goal: I want to learn how a marginal variational distribution $q_k$ is optimal in maximizing the evidence lower bound (locally) when it has the form $q_k^*\propto \exp\{\mathbb{E}_{\_k}[\log(p(z_k|Z_{\_k}, x)]\}$ where $x$ is some observed random variable, $k$ indexes the $k$th parameter of interest, and the notation $\_k$ is used to denote all indices but $k$.

Question: references I have come across simply state, paraphrased, "with Lagrange multipliers, we obtain this result". But how do we optimize a distribution using Lagrange multipliers? To add to my confusion, the distribution family for which we are optimizing over is not even constrained to parametric forms, which seems a little abstract to me.

An answer is preferred, but references are also accepted.

The notes I referenced can be found at https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf.
I am looking at the derivation of Equation (24) in particular.

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of Lagrange multipliers in optimizing functions of a finite number of real variables subject to constraints?  If so, the only additional concept you need is that of differentiating a functional, discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235446.

Comment: *But how do we optimize a distribution using Lagrange multipliers? To add to my confusion, the distribution family for which we are optimizing over is not even constrained to parametric forms, which seems a little abstract to me.*

It seems abstract because the notes have described variational inference abstractly. You may have missed the following 1. You *posit* a distributional family, such as $q(z_k) = \text{Dirichlet}(\alpha_k)$. 2. This distribution family is often 'parametrised' by a *variational parameter* $\alpha_k$.

Comment: 3. You then solve for the optimised variational parameter $\alpha_k$ by taking derivatives of the evidence lower bound with respect to the variational parameter $\alpha_k$, in your notation, $d\mathcal{L}_k / d \alpha_k$. The method of Lagrange multipliers supplies conditions under which this is an optimum.