Expected loss function from bias variance trade off (integral help)
I have a hard time understanding this formula. It's from bias-variance trade-off proof. and the expected loss function is as follows:
$$L(\hat f) := \mathbb E_D\mathbb E_{(x,y)}[(y-\hat f(x))^2]=\mathbb E_D\left[\iint (y-\hat f(x))^2 p(x,y)\,\text dx\text dy \right]
%[![enter image description here][1]][1]
$$
$\mathbb E_D$ corresponds to the training data, and $\mathbb E_{(x,y)}$ to the testing data. In order to find the optimal function $\hat f(\cdot)$, the derivative wrt $f(\cdot)$ is computed, and the formula becomes the following.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial f(x)}\iint (y-\hat f(x))^2 p(x,y)\,\text dx\text dy=2\int (y-\hat f(x)) p(x,y)\,\text dy = 0
%[![enter image description here][2]][2]
%[![enter image description here][3]][3]
$$
But what I don't understand with my rusty integral knowledge is where the inner integral part $(\text dx)$ went?
If it is because it belongs to $f(x)$, then shouldn't it be changed to something different like $f'(x)$? (For example, if $f(x) = 2x$, then after the integral wrt $x$, it should be $x^2$.)

This is a functional derivative: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235446 for an explanation.  (The notation here is misleading: the denominator of the derivative really should not have "$(x)$" after "$f$" and "$f$" ought to be "$\hat f$" everywhere.)

Please provide a reference for this very poor and mathematically incorrect description of the derivation.

May I insist on my earlier request to provide the reference since it otherwise makes the question imprecise and of lesser appeal to the community.

Why do you need that derivative at all? The proof proceeds with some algebra and properties of expectations

This is a functional derivative.
Employing the notation in my explanation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/236159/919, let $\mathcal L$ be the functional, let $h$ be any (integrable) function, and let $\delta$ be any number.  Then, from algebra (applied to the integrands) and linearity of the double integral, the change induced in $\mathcal L$ by changing $f$ a tiny bit to $f+\delta h$ is
$$\mathcal L[f + \delta h] - \mathcal L[f] = \delta \iint (-2h(x))(y - f(x))p(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\ + O(\delta^2).$$
A critical point (or stationary point) of $\mathcal L$ is a function $f$ for which this vanishes to first order in $\delta.$  (Examining the $\delta^2$ coefficient shows it's not negative--the integrand is a product of $h^2$ and $p$--implying any such critical points are local minima of the functional.)
Applying Fubini's theorem to express the coefficient of $\delta$ (a double integral) as an iterated single integral, we obtain
$$0 = -2 \int h(x) \left(\int (y-f(x))p(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dx.$$
Because $h$ is (essentially) arbitrary, the quantity it multiplies in the $x$ integral must be zero for this equation to hold for all $h,$ QED.

Notice that $f$ needn't even be a differentiable function, so that "$f^\prime$" might not be defined: the procedure still works.  This is a good hint that the functional derivative is not the usual derivative.  What it is, intuitively, is an extension of the difference quotient concept from one (or finitely many) variables to "variables" like $f$ in a function space that might be infinite dimensional.

Starting from the objective
$$\min_{\hat f}\mathbb E_D\left[\iint (y-\hat f(x))^2 p(x,y)\,\text dx\text dy \right]$$
the derivation of the optimal function$$\hat f: x\longmapsto \hat f(x)$$follows from finding the optimal value $\hat f(x)$ for each entry $x$, which means finding the solution to
$$\min_{\varphi\in\mathbb R} \mathbb E_D\left[\int (y-\varphi)^2 p(x,y)\,\text dy\right]\tag{1}$$
since
$$\mathbb E_D\left[\iint (y-\hat f(x))^2 p(x,y)\,\text dx\text dy \right]=\int \mathbb E_D\left[\int (y-\hat f(x))^2 p(x,y)\,\text dy\right]\,\text dx$$ by Fubini.
Differentiating the term in (1) wrt $\varphi$ leads to
$$\mathbb E_D\left[\int -2(y-\varphi) p(x,y)\,\text dy\right]=0\tag{2}$$
assuming the order of differentiation and integration can be exchanged.
